# VSCode - TypeScript language service died unexpectedly 5 times in the last 5 minutes

Tags: visual-studio-code

This error message keeps sliding down from the top every few seconds.  I click on the close button and it comes back again.  I am not and don't plan on using TypeScript in any of my projects.

[image]

Is there a way to "silent" this warning message?
Is there a way to change the frequency that the warnings slide down on the screen?

This is happening in VSCode 1.8.1 and 1.9 on Windows 10 and Windows 8.

Comment: I think Something is wrong with the new update. After I installed older version it worked.

Comment: related issue tickets: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88163, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150054, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169618, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178411

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work on TypeScript for VSCode.

The TypeScript language service powers language features for both TypeScript and JavaScript code. Without it, you do not get any suggestions or intellisense or any other nice language support.

Please [open an issue against VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if you are seeing this error. You can also try upgrading the version of TypeScript that VS Code uses to pick up the latest fixes and features: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

(I'm also looking into a better way to handle this message since it can be very spammy when the TypeScript service crashes continually)

Comment: Any progress on this?  It's killing my React development experience stone dead.

Comment: There are multiple issues that have been opened about this, all closed or locked without much progress.

Comment: Yes because this is a super generic error with lots of different root causes... You should file a new issue!

Comment: @MattBierner do you know if there is any movement on this?  I have a WSL2 ts/js dev container with very few plugins, but about 50 repos.  I've spent so so many hours of looking at logs etc, but I know I won't be able to produce a repro without taking ages.

I've enabled the logging and trawled through the logs but just can't find anything.

Answer (score 9):

I resolve my problem by use this way:

1. first, open your typescript.tsserver.log to "verbose"
   [image]
2. restart vscode, and open ts log
   [image]
3. and you will find when make your tsserver so slow, as for me, jest_cache is the problem. so I add a exclude in my tsconfig.json
   [image]
4. restart, and the problem solve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you figured out what was making the tsserver slow?

Comment: I did this and it says "TS Server has not started logging".

Answer (score 7):

To people getting here using WSL2 & Ubuntu(?)

`rm -rf ./vscode-server` worked for me

Comment: This worked for me. It did remove all the WSL extensions, so maybe uninstalling and re-installing them might work as well.

Comment: I deleted the `./vscode-server/data/logs` folder, then restarted VSCode and that fixed it for me.

Comment: from where should I execute this code

Answer (score 5):

you can try to install [this vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) to make vscode use latest typescript version

Comment: That fixed my TS error `The TypeScript language service died 5 times right after it got started. The service will not be restarted.` with VSC Version: 1.63.0

Comment: @Daniele If you found an answer helpful it is better to vote on it than leaving a confirmation comment. Comments can get deleted and votes move the post up the page so it is more visible to others

Comment: 28 December 2021: this did not work for me (latest version of VS Code)

Answer (score 4):

I the same problem with VSCode using a workspace Yarn and Typescript.  After a couple months without a solution, I tried updating the Yarn VSCode SDK using `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` as part of [these instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks) and that fixed my problem.

Comment: I had this problem while working in a project with NPM after trying out yarn a few months ago. I used the extension bisect feature to pin down this (deprecated) extension: `ark120202.vscode-typescript-pnp-plugin` as causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" extension worked for me.

The error always said that the workspace was using an old verison of typescript and that I should upgrade although I was up to date. It looks the workspace was using the latest dev build of typescript because of the extension or something like that maybe caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

For a temprary solution you need to rollback to an older version. In my case it worked with: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have the typescript compiler (`tsc`) installed on my system. So `npm install -g typescript` resolved my problem.

Comment: note that VS Code bundles TypeScript with itself- usually the latest version at the time of the VS Code version release.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to TypeScript v3.7.3 *and* using [VSCode Insider's Edition](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) seems to fix the issue for me.

There are multiple ways to upgrade.  One way is:

```
yarn add -D typescript@3.7.3
```

[image]

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84618#issuecomment-562290275

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my solution which I spent 1 week.

- Fallback version to `Version: 1.61.2 (Universal)`
- Rmove your local VsCode totaly.

  - quit it
  - remove it from your Application folder
  - remove the file `~/.vscode`

    - `rm -rf ~/.vscode`
- Install the vsCode `v1.61.2` and open it;
- Close the aoto update. **it's important**

  - find the menu `Code > preferences > settings`
  - search keyword of `update`
  - set `Application/Update/update > mode > none`
- Open your `ts` project

#### Hope help you

Answer (score 0):

took me a few confusing days, as it kept trying to default to 16.8 which I had not installed via nvm

I installed and un-installed 16.8, set the default and system aliases (always alias to a version number without any letters ['v']

Finally I found a posting that said, no matter what you have installed for nvm MacOS will always use the system Node if there is one.

So: `brew uninstall node` got rid of a version that I didn't was on my mac... I've been using nvm for many years, so I don't know how it got there.  Perhaps it came in as a dependency...

Since I use nvm, and always want the typescript support I pinned it to a particular version of node that I know has typescript installed globally

tsdk: /Users/ajoslin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting my local repo and re-cloning. I also did a `yarn cache clear`.