# Visual Studio code TypeScript language service died

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

have anyone faced with such a problem in VS Code : "The TypeScript language service died 5 times right after it got started" . Screens are below by link  :

[image]

[image]

*( Cannot paste screens due to low reputation =( for now )*

I use the latest TypeScript (4.5.2), so there no basic solution .
When I start VS code extension works well bit then fails. Have anyone faces with it?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026496/vscode-typescript-language-service-died-unexpectedly-5-times-in-the-last-5-min). Your question is probably a duplicate

Comment: @captain-yossarian , thanks for reply, There are no working solution by link you have shared.

Comment: I have opened an issue against  VS Code https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139728

Comment: This issue is not actual anymore. TypeScript new version fixed it. Just update up to 4.5.4 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139728

Comment: Uninstall vscode. Install Webstorm.

Comment: This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026496

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47299), we can fix it by updating the typescript version to latest - v4.5.5

```sh
npm i -g typescript
# or
npm i -g typescript@4.5.5
```

Update your vs-code to use this latest version of typescript.

1. Open vs code settings.
2. Search for `tsdk`
3. Update the path to globally installed typescript location. Example location for mac - `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib`
4. Restart your vs code

Comment: It is a good solution but I have faced this issue on latest available version of TypScript. Thats why update did not help because there was nothing to update =)

Answer (score 0):

This issue depends a lot on the project.

For my project it was:

1- Open VS Code settings.

2- Search for `tsdk`.

3- Update the path to your `typescript/lib` directory.

It could be in your `/usr/local/...` if you want to use the global installation. In my case, it was `/.yarn/sdks/typescript/lib`

4- Restart your VS Code.